# not able to type capital d on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I am not able to type capital d.

I am able to type A-Z without problem except d.

Can anyone tell me the possible problem please?

### Update:

ooooooooops
I found that I have a keyboard shortcut for shift+ d.

**Solved.** 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using a keyboard directly attached to the computer, or are you using some remote access system like Synergy or VNC or such?

Comment: Hmmm I'm going to say this is keyboard madness. Are you on a laptop? Is there a way for you to see if that key is dirty and/or broken. Try removing the key and pressing the trigger on the padding itself -- does that work?

Comment: It is directly connected to a desktop.

Comment: You should write up your solution as an answer then mark it as the accepted answer, then this will be closed. :)

Comment: You may need to wait 48 hours before it allows you to vote your own, but this is fine and completely acceptable. (said this on SO meta, can't find a similar SU meta that answers this though)

Answer (score 2):

I found there is a keyboard shortcut for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

I deleted this and it works fine.

Comment: Appreciated that you took the trouble to post an answer, which might help the next person with this problem.

Comment: Mark this as the correct answer please.